# Regroup rows with the same values in some columns if there is a condition (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I would like a method in Pandas to identify the rows with with the same values in A B C columns if in column D I have 'Invalid' for this group:

A B C D

0 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 0 Invalid

1 1 1

1 1 1

1 1 1

2 2 2

2 2 2

2 2 2 update

1 2 5

See table: I would like to identy the fist 3 rows because are duplicate for columns A B C(0 0 0)and I have at least a 'invalid' in column D.

I want in outputa boolean vector with True if my condition is satisfied.

Thanks you so much :)

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by "regroup". Do you want to add another column with the values of True or False?

Comment: I want to identify the rows that respect the condition. Please look the image attached.

Comment: Do you want a column where the value will be TRUE if it is not duplicate and False when it is a duplicate?

Comment: I updated the request maybe now it is more clearer

Comment: The question is very unclear and it does not give an idea what is the input and the required output. I would request you to plese read the guideline and edit your question so that me or some other people can help you. 

Hint: To test a question, you can read your own question pretending as an "answerer" and see if you can understand the problem or not.